# Using loops to create multiple columns at once

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, for-loop

I am new to writing loops in python and I was wondering if someone can help me here.

I have a situation where I need to create two new cols - polarity and subjectivity. There are **15 comments columns ColA - Col O** that I have for which I need to create such columns so that I can start with sentiment analysis. I am doing this the following way:

```
#Sentiment analysis of all the comments for col A:
from textblob import TextBlob
data_account[['polarity_A', 'subjectivity_A']] = df['A'].apply(lambda Text: 
pd.Series(TextBlob(Text).sentiment))

#Sentiment analysis of all the comments for col B:
data_account[['polarity_B', 'subjectivity_B']] = 
data_account['B'].apply(lambda Text:pd.Series(TextBlob(Text).sentiment))
```

The output will look something like this :

```
A  B  polarity_A subjectivity_A polarity_B subjectivity_B
```

How Can I write a loop on top of this code so that I have polarity and subjectivity columns for all the 15 comments columns at once? The new columns that are created should have a '_C' or '_D' and so on until '_o' which is the last comment column.

Comment: Do you have two dataframes? `df` and `data_account` or just `data_account`? Your source for `A` is different than your source for `B`

Comment: please add some code to create a sample of your source dataset

Comment: @eva-vw: I just have one dataframe data_account. The source for A and B are also the same. They are just two columns in one dataframe data_account..The code that I have attached is the sample code only. This creates the put[ut that I have shown .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data_account` contains just a column per comment "letter":

```py
for col in data_account.columns:
    data_account[[f"polarity_{col}", f"subjectivity_{col}"]] = data_account[col].apply(
        lambda Text: pd.Series(TextBlob(Text).sentiment)
    )
```